# Application restarts multiple times when ClickOnce updates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, clickonce

My application is a WPF App. I have decided to use ClickOnce to deploy my application. 
It works quite well, but when I launch a new version of my app I have to restart my app at least 2-3 times before ClickOnce will update with the new version of my app.

How can I configure it to update immediatly when I restart my application at the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Project Properties under `Publish` > `Updates...` you can set that the Application should check for updates `Before the Applications starts`

Comment: Thank you for your answer But I have already set it. It's not worked. I have to still restart my app at least 2-3 times.

Comment: @tanaponmaster thats weird. where do you deploy your app to? (local filesystem, ftp, web,...)